# isChecked() not working

Tags: java, android

I have made a simple app based on menu.the java code is

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView tv;
    CheckBox chb;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        chb=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.chbInFlate);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
       menu.add(0, 1, 0, "add");

        menu.add(0, 2, 0, "edit");
        menu.add(0, 3, 3, "delete");
        menu.add(1, 4, 1, "copy");
        menu.add(1, 5, 2, "paste");
        menu.add(1, 6, 4, "exit");

        return true;
    }

    public boolean OnPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        if(chb.isChecked()) {
            Log.d("my", "aaa");
            menu.setGroupVisible(1, true);
        } else {
            Log.d("my", "bbb");
            menu.setGroupVisible(1, false);
        }
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        Log.d("my", "bbb");
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("Menu Item");
        sb.append("\r\n Group id="+ String.valueOf(item.getGroupId()));
        sb.append("\r\n Item id="+ String.valueOf(item.getItemId()));
        sb.append("\r\n Order ="+ String.valueOf(item.getOrder()));
        sb.append("\r\n Title="+ item.getTitle());
        tv.setText(sb.toString());
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

#### layout:

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.add.MainActivity" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chbInFlate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="67dp"
        android:text="CheckBox" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Initially all 6 menu items are visible irrespective of the checkbox is checked or not.....now after putting log.d methods,messages are showing correctly in my logcat filter when one menu item is selected,but log.d is not responding for the isChecked method. why is this happening?

Comment: You need to call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` when the checkbox is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should call [`invalidateOptionsMenu()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#invalidateOptionsMenu%28%29) whenever the checkbox state changes.
2. `OnPrepareOptionsMenu()` has the wrong case. It should be [`onPrepareOptionsMenu()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29). Make sure to add the `@Override` annotation to avoid these kinds of problems.

Answer (score 0):

try adding this at the end of the onCreate method:

```
invalidateOptionsMenu();
```

It looks like the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12886751/jelly-bean-not-calling-onprepareoptionsmenu-when-opening-the-menu-for-the-firs)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        chb=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.chbInFlate);
        invalidateOptionsMenu()  
    }
```